# Develop React without packaging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, deployment, create-react-app

I started a CRA React project and now it's quite big so every time I save a change the webpack generates the bundle and it takes a while on my machine and it bothers me so maybe it's a dumb question but somehow, preferably an easy way, but is there any way to develop in React and visualize the App in the development stage without generating a package all the time, but only generating it when deploying?

Develop in React whithout bundle on very save moment.

Comment: You can move to `vite`. `vite` compiles under one second (because it doesn't compile everything into one bundle)

Comment: Is this migration easy and no problem?

Comment: It depends on how tied into CRA's functionality you are. [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) offers (initially) a very basic but highly customisable build system so you can probably match your current system quite quickly. There are a good number of migration guides you can search for [`1`](https://www.robinwieruch.de/vite-create-react-app/) [`2`](https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/migrating-from-create-react-app-cra-to-vite) for example.